# what does it mean: (*) as part as type in C

Tags: c

I read some example C code and saw this line:

```
Func((const float(*)[5])ptr);
```

When the func signature is:

```
Func(const float*)
```

`ptr` is a `float` 2d array. The question is what does the `(*)` mean?

Comment: Post the actual code please.

Comment: `const float(*)[5]ptr` looks like a syntax error to me, do you mean `const float (*ptr)[5]`?

Comment: The number of opening and closing parentheses in the first line doesn't match up.

Comment: I forgot closing parenthes, now the code is right. It supposed to be casting for ptr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the function would be declared as

```
void f( const float a[][5] ) { puts( "Inside f" ); }
```

and `ptr` had type for example

```
float ptr[10];
```

then this call

```
f( ( const float ( * )[5] )ptr );
```

uses casting from `float *`to `const float ( * )[5]`

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f( const float a[][5] ) { puts( "Inside f" ); }

int main(void) 
{
    float ptr[10];

    f( ( const float ( * )[5] )ptr );

    return 0;
}
```

This declaration

```
const float ( * )[5]
```

means a pointer to an array of 5 elements of type const float.

Or here is a more interesting example

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f( const float a[][5], size_t n ) 
{
    size_t i, j;

    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < 5; j++ ) printf( "%f ", a[i][j] );
        printf( "\n" );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    float p[10] = { 0.0f, 1.1f, 2.2f, 3.3f, 4.4f, 5.5f, 6.6f, 7.7f, 8.8f, 9.9f };

    f( ( const float ( * )[5] )p, 2 );

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
0.000000 1.100000 2.200000 3.300000 4.400000 
5.500000 6.600000 7.700000 8.800000 9.900000
```

As for your example then there is a type mismatch.

Comment: In your example a is eventually a pointer to float as any array.

Comment: @user2877748 It is a pointer to the first element of a two dimensional array. The element of a two dimensional array is a one-dimensional array.  So you are right.

Comment: the compiler and the linker don't check this type compatibility, right? it's only to help the code writter. Because it C the compiler doesn't know and cannot check the size of the array.

Comment: @user2877748 I have not understood what type compatibility you are saying. For example for your code snippet the compiler will issue an error because the type of function parameter and the type of the argument do not coincide.

Comment: Casting float* to float(*)[5] is not defined by C standard. You are breaking strict aliasing. It would be nice to strongly point that out in the answer.

Comment: @2501 Can you give references to the standard that say that I am breaking something. In my opinion it is a valid code and corresponds to C++ casting reinterpret_cast.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Sure take a look at c11, 6.5. p7. And there is a plethora of answers on strict aliasing on SO, you just have to search.

Comment: I ment in your example (it's the right example for my question) the check of the send argument type and the function argumetn type coincide. The compiler sees the ( const float ( * )[5] )p as const float pointer?

Comment: @2501 I do not see any contradiction. The elements of the array are accessed according to their types.

Comment: @user2877748 The compiler interpretates the argument as having type const float ( * )[5]

Comment: @VladfromMoscow   I employ you to research the matter, you might be surprised. For example nowhere in the standard it defines that `float*` and `float(*)[5]` have the same size or the same alignment requirements. Also those types are nowhere defined as compatible, and as you can see in rules of 6.5. p7. an object can only have its stored value accessed by an compatible object.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow And that is the problem, instead of researching the subject, you blindly stick to your beliefs, ignoring the facts.

Comment: @2501 The two pointers are correctly aligned because they have the same value. They address the same extent of memory.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow That may be on your machine, but standard permits them to not be. And they might not be on a different architecture that still follows the standard 100%. We are talking about `C` not compiler specific code right?( rhetorical question )  C code must follow the standard correctly, otherwise please note in the answer that your code doesn't.

Comment: @2501 The base type is float. The both pointers point to the same address. There is no any problem and this does not depend on a compiler. If you will find a compiler that produces different values for the pointers then let me know.

Comment: @2501 What you are saying is interesting but is not earnestly.  The address of any array and the address of the first element of the array coincide. So any array has alignment of its base element.

Comment: With gcc, `-fstrict-aliasing` says "an object of one type is assumed never to reside at the same address as an object of a different type". The point is to make it easier to optimize code. Values are floating around in the stack and registers. The compiler isn't necessarily going to emit code to sync updates via an incompatible pointer.

Comment: @eryksun Are a scalar object and an array compatible types? Consider declaration int *p. p can address either a scalar object of a first element of an array. Now use expression &a where a is an array. Does it have differemnt value than the address of the first element of the array?!

Comment: @VladfromMoscow ( Risking my own sanity ), I will trying to explain naively. That doesn't matter, you already stored a pointer into an incompatible pointer when you called the function, **Bam! undefined behavour**.

Comment: @2501 When the function is called its argument has the same type as the function parameter.

Comment: @2501 Where in the Standard is said that for example one dimensional array of base type T has different alignment than a two dimensional array of the same base type T?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Where does it say that it does? You can't just assume that. Standard specifically states what you **can** do, if something isn't stated then you **can't** do it.

Comment: @2501  If the standard does sat how arrays are aligned then it means only that the standard has a defect.

Comment: @VladfromMoscowOf  *Argument from fallacy* My logical circuits exploded, while reading your last comment.